# Django3: accounts/password_reset does not use admin.site.site_header

Tags: django, django-3

I have an app

```
main/
├── asgi.py
├── celery.py
├── __init__.py
├── settings.py
user/
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── ...
├── models.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

In `admin.py` the admin page title is set like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.site_header = settings.HOME_TITLE
```

Which works on `localhost:8000/admin/`.

But `http://localhost:8000/accounts/password_reset/`  still shows the standard *Django Administration* title. Is there a way to change that consistently or would I have to create my own template for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes in project **urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.site_header = settings.HOME_TITLE
admin.site.site_title = settings.HOME_TITLE
```

Comment: This does not change it.

Comment: @Sören, Have you added `admin.site.site_title`?

Comment: Yes, I added all of this to urls.py .

Comment: Strange, as you can see in source, it used `site_header` : https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html